# How can I display the visible number of health?

Tags: game-maker

I'm trying to create health that is just numbers, I know how to do the bar but I just want it to show.

Here is the gml you need to see

```
plvl = 1;

mphlth = 75 + (plvl * 25);

phlth = 100
if (phlth >= mphlth) {
    phlth = mphlth
}
draw_text(10,10,string(phlth));
```

I also tried with the following:

```
draw_text(10,30,"health: "+string(player1.phlth));
```

Is there anyway to display the health number?

Comment: In which event is this code located? You can only draw when executing from Draw Event.

Comment: i think it was i deleted the draw text to have the ability to play test all the other features the variables are still there is there anyway you can type the line or two of code to work since I gave the variables

Comment: i don't see why the code didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry I found it out on my own all I had to do was make it a global variable then type  draw_text(32,32,phlth);
numbers are changeable